# Accessing vuex actions inside a promise

Tags: firebase, vue.js, promise

I'm struggling to understand this conceptually.

So I'm trying to use a Vuex store action from within a second .then() function of a promise (  this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data())) , and I'm getting the error of TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined.

Why can't I access this in the .then() function?

```
 socialLogin () {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(cred => {
          const protoslug = cred.user.displayName + ' ' + cred.user.uid
          this.slug = slugify(protoslug, {
            replacement: '-',
            remove: /[$*_+~.()'"!\-:@']/g,
            lower: true
          })
          db.collection('users').doc(this.slug).set({
            alias: this.slug,
            role: 'customer',
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
            user_id: cred.user.uid
          })
          // set the user in the vuex store
          this.$store.dispatch('setUser', cred.user)
          return cred.user
        })
        .then((cred) => {
          db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', cred.uid)
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                console.log(doc.data())
                this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data())
              })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
            })
        })
    }
```

I can see that the data is returned as it is logged out in the console. The project is in typescript, so its preventing me from trying self = this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To propagate the value of `this` all the way down, you need to always use arrow functions. Change these lines:

```js
.then(function (querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                console.log(doc.data())
                this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data())
              })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
            })
```

to use arrow functions:

```js
.then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.data())
                this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data())
              })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
            })
```

Comment: Are these ES6 functions? I think I need to look over this in more detail. That was the answer - thank you!

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) inherit the context in which they are declared whereas regular `function` expressions get the context in which they are called. It can be funky, and using arrow functions often leads to what feels more "expected".